# Disable folder public access from htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website from which you can downloads resources.

What I want is to disable public access for the folder on which the items are stored but allowed them to be accessed by website for download.

I've used `Order deny,allow` in .htaccess but if i use that I can't download from the website.

It will will give me error 404 same as trying to type direct url for the file. The download is performed.

I have the following code:

```
       $link = $item->link;

        $link_headers = get_headers($link);

        //Headers
        if(isset($link_headers[0]))
        {
            header($link_headers[0]);

        }//if exists
        if(isset($link_headers[1]))
        {
            header($link_headers[1]);

        }//if exists
        if(isset($link_headers[2]))
        {
            header($link_headers[2]);

        }//if exists
        if(isset($link_headers[3]))
        {
            header($link_headers[3]);

        }//if exists
        if(isset($link_headers[4]))
        {
            header($link_headers[4]);

        }//if exists
        if(isset($link_headers[5]))
        {
            header($link_headers[5]);

        }//if exists
        if(isset($link_headers[6]))
        {
            header($link_headers[6]);

        }//if exists
        if(isset($link_headers[7]))
        {
            header($link_headers[7]);

        }//if exists
        if(isset($link_headers[8]))
        {
            header($link_headers[8]);

        }//if exists

        readfile($link);

        exit;
```

Thing is if i put .htaccess with deny all into the  folder that holds all the items for download then download will not work anymore because i don't have permission and i want that to be available only for people who try to download from direct link to the file from url.

Comment: do you want to password protect the folder? are you looking for some sort of user level access restrictions?

Comment: What i want is to not allow access to a file from a direct link.For example accessing www.website.com/downloads/file32.jpg like this should return permission denied.

Comment: You must use path of your file. I guess you use link of your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to download via a script that checks for the http-referrer. The header can of course be modified manually, but I think doing something more complex than this would be an overkill:

```
/*
Change your download links to point to a php script, or use .htaccess to rewrite downloads to the same file
*/
<a href="download.php?file=somefile.zip">Download</a>

//download.php

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "your_downloads_page.html") {
    $file = $_GET['file'];
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

However **be sure to add some security checks** so that users can't download files they shouldn't be allowed to. Perhaps filter all slashes and double dots.

Answer (score 0):

If you protect your file and file path, you can use a download.php file.

download.php file content

```
<?php
// Connect to db and get file information from db.
// $db_filename and $db_filetype getting from db

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=def.file_type"); // def.pdf
header("Content-type: " . $db_filetype);  // application/pdf
readfile("/path/of/your/files/".$db_filename); // /project/home/downloads/abc.pdf
```

Usage :

```
download.php?file_id=1
```

This usage is protect your folder and file name, but it use database.